# How can I save a date field from JavaScript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, angularjs

I want to save a date datatype field in salesforce from angularjs form. It is giving me error saying invalid date format. Here is my code:

```
 <div class='input-group date' id='assignWODate'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="item.assignedDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
 </div>
```

In my controller I am able to save date as per below mentioned code.How to pass dynamic value to new Date() method?

```
var dispatchTechDetails = new WorkOrderModels.wo({
    Id: $routeParams.woId,
    AssignedDate__c: new Date(dateValue),
    Assigned_Technician__c: techName
});
```

Comment: Can you please post your controller code? It should work with newInstance method.

Comment: @OlesMalkov I have posted my updated controller code in the question above. Thnx

Answer (score 3):

> Date format for Salesforce should be in ISO 8601 format as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

- Try the following formatting in Angular Js

  ```
  {{item.date | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'}}
  ```

**Update:**

For date try the snippet below:

```
 Date assignedDate = Date.parse('03/01/2016');
```

Comment: I have created a date field and not date/time field in salesforce..Will it work for date field as well?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please refer that

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, I am formatting the bootstrap date using jquery and just passing the form value to controller below is my code:

HTML code:

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
             <label class="control-label col-md-4" style="text-align: left;" for="Date">Date:</label>
             <div class="col-md-8">                 
                <div class='input-group date' id='assignWODate'>                        
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="woAssignedDate"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>                               
             </div>
        </div>
```

My controller code:

```
    var assignedDate = $scope.woAssignedDate;

    var dispatchTechDetails = new WorkOrderModels.wo({      
                        AssignedDate__c:  new Date(assignedDate)

                    });
```